# Zsh and git-flow error

Tags: git, zsh, git-flow

I'm trying to use the oh-my-zsh git-flow plugin and getting the following error.

```
➜  ~/www/ git:(develop) git flow feature feature
flags:FATAL zsh shwordsplit option is required for proper zsh operation
```

Is this an issue with the plugin? or a configuration issue?

EDIT: Using `setopt shwordsplit` doesn't help

```
➜  ~/www/ git:(develop) ✗ setopt shwordsplit 
➜  ~/www/ git:(develop) ✗ git flow feature  
flags:FATAL zsh shwordsplit option is required for proper zsh operation
```

EDIT 2: Using `set -x`

```
(k3)➜  ~  git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:1> print -sr -- git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:2> fc -p /home/gaurav/.directory_history/home/gaurav/history
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:1> print -sr -- git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:2> fc -p /home/gaurav/.directory_history/home/gaurav/history
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:1> print -sr -- git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:2> fc -p /home/gaurav/.directory_history/home/gaurav/history
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:1> print -sr -- git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:2> fc -p /home/gaurav/.directory_history/home/gaurav/history
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:1> print -sr -- git flow feature
+_per-directory-history-addhistory:2> fc -p /home/gaurav/.directory_history/home/gaurav/history
+omz_termsupport_preexec:1> emulate -L zsh
+omz_termsupport_preexec:2> setopt extended_glob
+omz_termsupport_preexec:3> local 'CMD='
+omz_termsupport_preexec:4> title '' '%100>...>git flow feature%<<'
+title:1> [[ '' == true ]]
+title:1> [[ '' == *term* ]]
+title:4> [[ xterm == screen* ]]
+title:6> [[ xterm == xterm* ]]
+title:7> print -Pn '\e]2;%100\>...\>git\ flow\ feature%\<\<\a'
+title:8> print -Pn '\e]1;\a'
+/usr/bin/zsh:1310> git flow feature
flags:FATAL zsh shwordsplit option is required for proper zsh operation
+omz_termsupport_precmd:1> title '%15<..<%~%<<' %n@%m: '%~'                                                                                                                                                                           
+title:1> [[ '' == true ]]
+title:1> [[ '' == *term* ]]
+title:4> [[ xterm == screen* ]]
+title:6> [[ xterm == xterm* ]]
+title:7> print -Pn '\e]2;%n@%m:\a'
+title:8> print -Pn '\e]1;%15\<..\<%~%\<\<\a'
+/usr/bin/zsh:1311> git_prompt_info
+git_prompt_info:1> ref=+git_prompt_info:1> git symbolic-ref HEAD
+git_prompt_info:1> ref='' 
+git_prompt_info:1> return
```

EDIT 2: More information about the set-up

```
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Oct  7 22:12 /bin/sh -> /usr/bin/zsh
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /usr/bin/zsh 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 28 Oct  2 13:49 /usr/bin/zsh -> /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /bin/zsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Oct  2 13:49 /bin/zsh -> /etc/alternatives/zsh
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct  2 13:49 /etc/alternatives/zsh-usrbin -> /bin/zsh4
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /bin/zsh4 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 688656 Mar 30  2012 /bin/zsh4
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) ls -l /etc/alternatives/zsh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Oct  2 13:49 /etc/alternatives/zsh -> /bin/zsh4
(k3)➜  K3 git:(feature/ebay_listings) /bin/sh -c 'echo $0 B$BASH_VERSION Z$ZSH_VERSION'
/bin/sh B Z4.3.17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is configuration issue completely explained in the error message:

> zsh shwordsplit option is required for proper zsh operation

. You have to add `setopt shwordsplit` to your zshrc. Better if you convince git-flow authors that this option is inconvenient: with it set `command $var` if var is scalar can result in command being called with any number of arguments (depending on how much spaces/tabs/newlines there are in the string) and you have to type `command "$var"` instead. Without: with one, equal to `$var`.

Comment: @GauravDadhania Wondering then how are you getting this error (`git flow feature <Tab>`?). I started oh-my-zsh with `plugins=(git-flow)` and `ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh` set, ensured that `shwordsplit` is disabled and tried to reproduce the issue. Nothing bad happend, completion works as intended. `set -x` showed that zsh is using the plugin in question. What do you see when reproducing the issue with `set -x` (who throws?). Quick googling has shown that it may come frome `shflags.sh` shell library, but it is not in oh-my-zsh source tree.

Comment: Pasted relevant output after `set -x`.

Comment: @GauravDadhania As far as I see, this has nothing to do with your zsh setup, but is a problem with `git flow` script. Additional pro: git flow does use shflags.sh library. What is very strange is that there is explicit `#!/bin/sh` at the very start of the script. Even if `/bin/sh` is a symlink to `/bin/zsh`, `zsh` will switch to POSIX shell emulation mode and thus will enable requested option. It won’t do so if `/bin/sh` is a script like `#!/bin/zsh\n/bin/zsh "$@"`, but this is rather strange.

Comment: Thus the following questions: where did you get `git-flow`? What is `/bin/sh`: symlink, script or binary; and which package it belongs to (assuming you are on linux and it was installed using some package manager)? Alternative: What does `/bin/sh -c 'echo $0 B$BASH_VERSION Z$ZSH_VERSION'` output, it is easier and should provide required data?

Comment: `/bin/sh` is a symlink. I've added the data you have requested. Really appreciate your help :)

Comment: Both `git-flow` and `zsh` were installed using APT.

Comment: @GauravDadhania Ah, I caught the problem: `shwordsplit` *is* being set correctly when calling zsh via `sh` symlink. But the code that `shflags.sh` uses for testing this option being set is completely *incorrect*: according to the doc `setopt` used to test this prints only options whose values differ from default *in current emulation*. “Current emulation” is “sh” and thus `shwordsplit` is the default hence `setopt | grep "^shwordsplit$"` used in `shflags.sh` shows nothing.

Comment: I opened the [issue](https://github.com/nvie/shFlags/issues/1) there. By the way, what is that alternatives mechanism? I would rather suggest that you use it to switch back to bash/dash (whatever is already installed and is the default on your system) as a `/bin/sh` shell. Alternatively you will have to wait until this issue will be fixed in the upstream then until this fix will be incorporated by your distributive maintainers.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. Is there something I can do in the meanwhile to get rid of the error?

Comment: @GauravDadhania Follow my suggestion and use `/bin/bash` or `/bin/dash` as the shell for `/bin/sh`. I was wrong saying about alternatives: I found Ubuntu on one of my computers and it has the same symlink picture, except for `sh` being a symlink for `dash`. And “no alternatives for sh” from `update-alternatives --config sh` with “only one alternative for zsh: nothing to configure” (both messages in Russian, you may get slightly different ones). Wondering how did you get `/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/zsh`. Do you have `dash` installed at all?

Comment: I manually edited that symlink from `/bin/sh -> /usr/bin/zsh` as there was a symlink from `/bin/sh -> /bin/zsh` after I used `chsh`.

Comment: @GauravDadhania Are you sure about chsh? It is not a purpose of this tool, it should just edit `/etc/passwd`. It did only this both on my Ubuntu netbook and on all Gentoo systems. If you can reproduce the behavior you should file a bug report to your distro bug tracker.

Comment: Yep, sure about `chsh`. I did something similar to http://superuser.com/questions/231735/how-do-i-change-my-default-shell-from-bash-to-zsh